# Working out Conditional Probability of New born children

Tags: probability

When a child is born into a family the probability of being born male is 0.5 and female 0.5. The probability of sex of subsequent babies is independent of previous births.

It asks if 4 babies are born into a family what is probably that exactly 1 female is born GIVEN that at least 1 female is born.

Now if I write out all the different possibilities

$MMMM$,$MMMF$ (X 4), $MMFF$ (X 6), $MFFF$ (X 4), $FFFF$

Total $16$

THen since there are 15 females the set reduces and there are 4 possibilities of 1 female only

If at this stage define Event A is at least 1 female, Event B exactly 1 fenale
So $P(B|A) = 4/15$

Problem I have though is how to use formula to obtain correct answer. Reason being I am not sure I am using right probabilities.

I have $P(B|A) = P(A \cap B)/P(A)$

I've used $P(A) =15/16$

And P(A) X P(B) = ? X 1/4 which makes P(A) = 1 if you sub into formula. Doesn't make sense. Can someone she'd light on the matter please?

Bruce A level Maths Tutor

Comment: You have $P(A \cap B)=P(B)=\frac4{16}$ Thus $P(B|A)=\frac{4/16}{15/16}$

Comment: By the way this is OCR S1, if you hadn't already guessed.

Comment: What do you mean with that comment ? What is OCR S1 ?

Comment: Thanks Calculus so how is P(AandB) = P(A), ate you related to YT CaucusExpert? Like her!

Comment: No, it is $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$. A is is the event that at least 1 child is female. B is the event that exactly 1 child is female (your definition). The **intersection** is that 1 child is female. // No I´m not related to her. It´s a nickname in my case.

Comment: That's what just clicked a few seconds ago but thanks for helping me end a week long journey trying to get 20 of these types of questions for a student. I love doing them but the student needs to know the answer quick cos they're suffering too! Good to know there's people out there that can respond in minutes and all is good again in my world again. Yes was just after her mobile really, just the way she solves problems with Lagrange Multipliers!! :-O Take care

Comment: Good luck with your student and have fun by teaching her/him.

Comment: I am she is wonderful